# How to export GridView data to pdf file in Asp.net and C#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

Currently I am facing the tedious problem of exporting complete GridView data to the pdf file so that the user can save it. I am using C# as the language in Asp.net 3.5. Kindly guide me.

The gridview contains only text values.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nearly all the links use the iTextSharp ... is it reliable ... any copyright issue or something. Further is there any other way of doing it other than iTextSharp ?

Comment: iTextSharp is reliable but you'll find it's poorly documented.  It's also open source.  http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

Comment: Please try to use method in this tip([http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/190144/Export-Database-to-Excel-PDF-HTML-RTF-XML-etc-for-.aspx](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/190144/Export-Database-to-Excel-PDF-HTML-RTF-XML-etc-for-.aspx)). It may be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Export GridView to Pdf using iTextSharp ASP.NET](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2008/12/export-gridview-to-pdf-using-itextsharp.html)
[Exporting GridView to PDF](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/29759-Exporting-GridView-PDF.aspx)

I haven't done this myself.

Answer (score 1):

[nFOP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nfop/) + XSLT + XML = pdf | doc | HTML

open source no cost :)

K

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Kindly share any link that illustrates its implementation of exporting gridview data to pdf.

Comment: http://nfop.sourceforge.net/article.html should give you an idea on how to use it, you need "Microsoft Visual J # NET Redistributable Package" to run nFOP.

K

Answer (score 0):

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    /* Verifies that the control is rendered */
}

protected void GeneratePDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=UserDetails.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("width", "15%");
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("font-size", "10px");
    GridView1.Style.Add("text-decoration", "none");
    GridView1.Style.Add("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;");
    GridView1.Style.Add("font-size", "8px");
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A2, 7f, 7f, 7f, 0f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();   
}
```